# Word for an entity, specifically a city, which is of the same nationality as you?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word to describe a city (or any entity) that is part of the same country or state, similar to the meaning of compatriot, but as an adjective.

"Allied" is close, but it is too distant as it could be an entity of a friendly state, not necessarily part of your own.

Comment: *federated* comes to mind

Comment: You mean 'analogous to **compatriot**' rather than *comrade*.

Comment: @Kris Yes you're correct.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think that's a good answer.

Comment: @Erofire Why do you 'think' so?

Comment: Because I don't have enough expertise with writing English to say for sure that's a good answer. It conveys the meaning I intended in an official tone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about "fellow"? I think that would work. As in "fellow Americans" or "their fellow cities."

Comment: Where did you hear 'fellow cities'?

Comment: @Kris How about [here](http://www.floridagreenconference.com/100cities.html), in Florida?

Comment: I think this is about as close as we're going to get: 'Fellow Americans / New Yorkers / citizens . . .'. It's less usual in the UK, though 'we must help our fellow man / believers' would work.

Comment: I think this is the most applicable answer, since it conveys the meaning well and is more conversation friendly than "federated".

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest **federated**.

From [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/federated),

> **federated**
>   adjective
>   (of a country) having a federal system of government   ⇒ *"Whether to stay in the federated state or become independent is a decision that has to be made by the people."*

Comment: I'm afraid you did not understand the Q.

Comment: @Kris Without more context, it's hard to decide. By the way if the OP is looking for *compatriot* but for city/town/state and an adjective one at that, I believe that *compatriot* could be used with a city/town/state, and as an adjective too. English allows us to use nouns as adjectives in appropriate contexts.

Comment: This is a very good answer in my opinion, but I think the other one can be more widely applied in conversation. I wish I could vote this up but I have no reputation.

Comment: Don't worry. As long as you get your answer, I'm happy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cities are often described as being 'twinned':

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_cities

Note that the above description refers to cities which are geographically close to each-other but, in Europe, towns and cities often (and arguably fairly arbitrarily) honorarily link with another location (usually in a different country) in order to attempt to establish closer cultural ties.

Comment: This does not answer the question, I'm afraid.